# TypeError: Can't pack data into an AEDesc (unsupported type): Decimal('13.3400')

Tags: python, psycopg2, xlwings

I'm trying to use xlwings to write data from an SQL query to a .xlsm file so that I can run a VBA macro on it.

I'm using psycopg2 for the SQL query and the data returned is being stored into a variable (data) as a list of tuples containing many decimals stored like that shown below:

```
...Decimal('182.10'), Decimal('84.88'), Decimal('136.13')...
```

When I run the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw    

wb = xw.Book('templates/macros.xlsm')
sheet = wb.sheets[0]

sheet['A1'].value = headers
sheet['A2'].value = data

wb.save('output.xlsx')

wb.close()
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Can't pack data into an AEDesc (unsupported type): Decimal('13.3400')
```

Can anyone explain what's going on? My guess that excel doesn't recognise Decimal() as a float? Does anyone have a workaround? or a simple way to convert the decimals to floats? xlwings has some converters but I don't think it covers decimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It appears that psycopyg (at least in the latest version: 3) had a method for this:

```
conn.adapters.register_loader("numeric", psycopg.types.numeric.FloatLoader)
```

[ref: psycopg documents](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/adapt.html#adapt-example-float)